# How to use OrderBy with findAll in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Data and want to get data sorted by id from database.When I write findAllByOrderById,error occured.I think error code is "No property id found for type Employee!"
But I don't know where to fix.
Repository

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    public List<Employee> findAllByOrderById();

}
```

Model

```
@Table(name = "employees")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id", length = 8)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer emp_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String emp_code;

    @Column(name = "emp_name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String emp_name;
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        List<Employee> emplist = empRepository.getAllEmployeesOrderById();

        model.addAttribute("emplist", emplist);
        return "view/index";
    }
}
```

View

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>日報管理システム</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="parent" th:include="app"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 th:text="${title}"></h1>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="emp : ${emplist}" th:object="${emp}">
            <td th:text="*{emp_id}"></td>
            <td th:text="*{emp_name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
</body>
```

Error code

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List spring.repositries.EmployeeRepository.findAllByOrderById()! No property id found for type Employee!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List spring.repositries.EmployeeRepository.findAllByOrderById()! No property id found for type Employee!

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Employee!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the naming you should use for the method should be:

```
findAllByOrderByEmp_IdAsc()
```

or

```
findAllByOrderByEmp_IdDesc()
```

depending on your need.

Full docs for query creation method naming [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

As a recommendation also in Java, field naming usually used is camelCase.

So for example if your field would be named `empId` your method will be named `findAllByOrderByEmpIdAsc()`

Comment: Sorry,I can get data,but data is not sorted.Is this another problem?

Comment: Yep, you might have to add "Asc" or "Desc" at the end